# MarkLogic Express Sample Application: The Oscars

Tags: marklogic

The sample database comes with 9 documents.   Is there a more extensive version of this database with more entries so that I may see how the sample application handles large search results?  The namespace for these documents is http://marklogic.com/wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the ninja demo at http://developer.marklogic.com/try/ninja/index - there are ~5 million emails (plus attachments) in that database.

You might also look at http://boingboing.demo.marklogic.com/ - which has 11 years of boingboing content in it.